# C# How to access static field of a public struct

Tags: c#

I am trying to access a `static` field of the `struct` which I already defined as public.
However, I still got "inaccessible due to its protection level" Can anyone help me?

```
public class Program
{
    public struct AT_CMD
    {
        static int x = 7;
       static  byte[] cmd_mode = new byte[3] { 0x2B, 0x2B, 0x2B };
       static  byte[] end_device_assoc = new byte[4] { 0x41, 0x54, 0x41, 0x31 };
      //should be 0 for end device, default is 0
       static  byte[] data_rate = new byte[4] { 0x41, 0x54, 0x42, 0x44 }; //3 for 9600, 5 for 38400
       static  byte[] channel = new byte[4] { 0x41, 0x54, 0x43, 0x48 }; //0x0B-0x1A
       static  byte[] Dest_addr_high = new byte[4] { 0x41, 0x54, 0x44, 0x48 }; //0 FOR 16bit
       static  byte[] Dest_addr_low = new byte[4] { 0x41, 0x54, 0x44, 0x4C };
       static  byte[] my_addr = new byte[4] { 0x41, 0x54, 0x4D, 0x59 }; // 0-0xFFFF
       static  byte[] carriage_return = new byte[1] { 0x0D };
   }  

    static void Main()
    {
        int y = AT_CMD.x;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default fields are **private**. Add the most limiting modifier that will still allow you to work with the structure.

```
public struct AT_CMD
{
    public static int x = 7;
}  

static void Main()
{
    int y = AT_CMD.x;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Change it to:

```
  public struct AT_CMD
  {
        public static int x = 7;

        // ...
  }
```

Just making a `struct` `public` doesn't affect its members, the members of the `struct` will be `private` by default unless you specify otherwise.

**UPDATE**: Addressing the confusion on default access, `internal` is the default access for the `struct` or `class` itself if declared at the namespace level (not nested in another class/struct):

> Classes and structs that are declared directly within a namespace (in
>   other words, that are not nested within other classes or structs) can
>   be either public or internal. Internal is the default if no access
>   modifier is specified.

Whereas, the fields in a `class` or `struct` always default to `private`:

> The access level for class members and struct members, including
>   nested classes and structs, is private by default.

From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx).

Comment: thanks a lot, so even it's static, still it's private...right?

Comment: @gpakillsme: No, technically the default is `internal`, though the distinction might not be important for your case.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx) for more information.

Comment: @BlueRaja: Actually, internal is the default for a non-nested struct/class itself (that is, `struct AT_CMD` is same as `internal struct AT_CMD` if non-nested).  The default for class/struct members is `private`.

Comment: @BlueRaja: No worries :-) the fact that the default for some things change based on scope but not others can be a wee bit confusing.

Answer (score 4):

The struct is public, but the members are not.

Answer (score 2):

Declare them like this:

```
public static  byte[] cmd_mode = new byte[3] { 0x2B, 0x2B, 0x2B };
```

However, it looks as though you mean these to be constants.  In that case, they should really be declared like this:

```
public static readonly IEnumerable<byte> cmd_mod = new byte[3] { 0x2B, 0x2B, 0x2B };
```

Comment: I'd recommend a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` here, if for nothing else but clarity.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` is rarely used in practice - for whatever reason, `IEnumerable<T>` is almost *always* preferred *(probably because it doesn't require a copy)*.  That being said, `IEnumerable<T>` doesn't have an indexer while `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` does, so if that is important, `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` may be your only choice.